# I got this error when I run my Android app on Sony telephone

Tags: android, native

The error appears in google play like the following :
Native crash
in unknown.unknown

```
  Build fingerprint: 'Sony/C5303/C5303:4.3/12.1.A.0.266/9f5_nw:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    pid: 13092, tid: 13208, name: AsyncTask #2 >>> com.imona.android <<<
    signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 41f85000 r1 00000001 r2 00000003 r3 00000000
    r4 5ddc2284 r5 5f07ae9c r6 5f01b818 r7 000035f2
    r8 40912540 r9 5ddc2284 sl 00000000 fp 00000036
    ip 5f01b3b4 sp 6025ada0 lr 00000000 pc 5f8d8122 cpsr 80000030
    d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
    d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
    d4 0009228000000000 d5 0000000010001000
    d6 0000000000000000 d7 000000003f800000
    d8 4434000000000000 d9 0000000042f80000
    d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
    d16 0000000100250002 d17 00000001001c0101
    d18 5750a19857542e40 d19 57542ee85750a1d0
    d20 5750a2785750a240 d21 57542d285750a2b0
    d22 57542e0857542d60 d23 57542eb057542e78
    d24 0000000000000000 d25 0000000000000000
    d26 3ff0000000000000 d27 0000000000000000
    d28 3ff0000000000000 d29 0000000000000000
    d30 0000000000000000 d31 c044000000000000
    scr 68000013

    backtrace:
    #00 pc 00023122 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

    code around pc:
    5f8d8100 00000000 5907d486 5907d482 5effae3c
    5f8d8110 f85f0050 68010008 60013101 696968e8
    5f8d8120 b13069aa 0203f04f 429168c1 aff9f47f
    5f8d8130 6169e002 e00361aa 61aa6169 de00e004
    5f8d8140 0038f8df 47886ef1 4300e000 47806e70
    5f8d8150 5ddc228e 4300e000 47806e70 5ddc2254
    5f8d8160 00000001 5ad20001 00000000 5788d210
    5f8d8170 00180103 00000001 00000000 5ddc2284
    5f8d8180 5effae40 f85f0030 68010008 60013101
    5f8d8190 682968a8 f2804288 1c2d8007 4300e000
    5f8d81a0 47806e70 5907d4d4 4300e000 47806e70
    5f8d81b0 5907d4fc 00000002 00000000 00000000
    5f8d81c0 577428f0 005e0101 00000001 00000000
    5f8d81d0 5effae44 f85f006c 68010008 60013101
    5f8d81e0 68e96928 0040eb00 0040ea4f b1996128
    5f8d81f0 f200688a 60ab0300 b182602a f2026897

    code around lr:
    00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
    000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
```

what could I understand from this ?

Comment: Which app you're trying to run on your sony mobile and can you post some of your code ?

Comment: Are you using the NDK? That's a native code dump, not a Java stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think he is not using NDK. At least I'm not, and I'm getting the exactly same damn report from mainly Samsung and HTC devices running Android 4.4.

Comment: @0101100101: Then you are tripping over some OS-level bug. Nothing a Java-only Android app can do can generate a dump like that -- that's only from a crash in native (C/C++) code. If you are seeing it from multiple manufacturers, it is probably a bug in Android itself (whereas a single-manufacturer crash is more likely to be a problem with that manufacturer's tinkering with Android). If it is from some recent release of Android (say, 4.4), it might be worth filing [a bug report](http://b.android.com).